# onrender Web Application displaying server and not front end react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, render

Im using Render to host my MERN web application, and after build and deployment on their online shell, the actual website doesnt work. Instead of displaying the front-end React like its supposed to, its displaying the backend server of my server.js file. As in going to the website, the first thing you'll see is "Welcome", as shown on my server.js.

server.js

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config("");
import connectDB from "./db/connect.js";

import notFoundMiddleWare from "./middleware/not-found.js";
import errorHandlerMiddleware from "./middleware/error-handler.js";

import authRouter from "./routers/authRouter.js";
import userRouter from "./routers/userRouter.js";
import postRouter from "./routers/postRouter.js";

app.use(express.json());

//middleware
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome");
});
app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ msg: "it works" });
});
app.get("/api/v1", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ msg: "API" });
});

app.use("/api/v1/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/user", userRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/post", postRouter);
app.use(notFoundMiddleWare);
app.use(errorHandlerMiddleware);
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URL);
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Server is listening at Port: ${port}`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    error;
  }
};

start();
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "setup-production": "npm run install-client && npm run build-client && npm install",
    "install-client": "cd client && npm install",
    "build-client": "cd client && npm run build",
    "server": "nodemon server --ignore client",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \" npm run server\" \" npm run client\""
  }
```

Render Dashboard
[image]

The rest of my code can be found here: https://github.com/hetyug04/blogify
and the active website: https://blogify-xiax.onrender.com/